# Minimal filebeat config: syslog -> file

Tags: syslog, filebeat

In an attempt to walk before running I thought I'd set up a *filebeat* instance as a syslog server and then use `logger` to send log messages to it.

My Docker Compose configuration for setting up *filebeat* is

```
filebeat:
  image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.3.1
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
  command: filebeat -v -c /config-dir/filebeat.yml
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - ./log-cfg/filebeat.yml:/config-dir/filebeat.yml
    - ./beat-out/:/beat-out/
```

The file `filebeat.yml` contains

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: syslog
    protocol.tcp.host: "localhost:5000"

output.file.path: "/beat-out"

logging:
  level: debug
  to_files: true
```

Bringing up *filebeat* with `docker-compose up filebeat` succeeds. And sending log messages using `logger --server localhost --port 5000 --tcp --rfc3164 "An error"` succeeds too. However, there is nothing printed to any file in `./beat-out/`.

Attaching to the running instance and inspecting the log (`/usr/share/filebeat/logs/filebeat`) doesn't help me understand what's missing. A log can be found at http://ix.io/1gdq. Also, nothing appears in the *filebeat* log when sending a syslog message with `logger`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer with some help.

The configuration of *filebeat* should be

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: syslog
    protocol.tcp.host: ":5000"

output.file.path: "/beat-out"

logging:
  level: debug
  to_files: true
```

Comment: Thanks, did you manage to get `log.source.address` right under docker? I am having one host but different ports for different hosts.